# How to move code written using #ifdef to support multiple platforms into a library function?

Tags: c++, c++11

We have a C++ project that is supporting multiple platforms (windows, linux, and mac).

To support multiple platforms, we have the below code snippet to close an existing socket for all the platforms.

```
#ifdef _WIN32
       closesocket(m_nSocketHandle);
#elif __APPLE__
      close(m_nSocketHandle);
#elif __linux__
        shutdown(m_nSocketHandle,SHUT_RDWR);
#endif
```

Similarly we are using other APIs for eg mkdir for different OS:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
        if (0 == _mkdir(m_hStrDirectoryPath.c_str()))
#else
    #ifdef __linux
            char mkcmd[500];
            sprintf(mkcmd, "mkdir -p %s", SDK_PATH);
            system(mkcmd);
             if (0 == mkdir(m_hStrDirectoryPath.c_str(), 0777))

    #else
            if (0 == mkdir(m_hStrDirectoryPath.c_str(), 0777))
    #endif
#endif
```

Instead of writing the code like this for all platforms or operating systems can we write a library (for eg., commonlib) by using the above code in the below function:

for eg.,

```
close_socket()
{
#ifdef _WIN32
      closesocket(m_nSocketHandle);
#elif __APPLE__
      close(m_nSocketHandle);
#elif __linux__
        shutdown(m_nSocketHandle,SHUT_RDWR);
#endif
}
```

And call this function from the main application. is this possible?

Can someone provide a sample to understand this?

Comment: *is this possible?* Yep, that is exactly how you would do it.

Comment: That's what we've done on my team.  My team writes our code to our edge abstraction (which one could put in, say, `namespace Edge`), and then insulate our core code from the platform implementation code through that abstraction.  Instead of having the implementation have all the `#if/#elif` checks, we instead have `Edge/Win/WinSocket.cpp`, and `Edge/Mac/MacSocket.cpp`, and `Edge/Lnx/LnxSocket.cpp`

Comment: Another option I've used in the past is to create multiple files (i.e. close_socket_win32.cpp, close_socket_apple.cpp, close_socket_linux.cpp) each with the implementation for one platform and have your build system select the correct one to compile based on what platform you're building for.

Comment: FYI, shutting down a socket and closing a socket are two separate operations. `shutdown()` does not close the socket descriptor and free resources, it merely stops data flow on the connection. Your Linux build still needs to call [`close()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html) on the socket descriptor, not (or, at least, in addition to) calling [`shutdown()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/shutdown), or else it will leak resources. So really, you should be doing this instead: `#ifdef _WIN32 closesocket(m_nSocketHandle); #else close(m_nSocketHandle); #endif`...

Comment: Alternatively, you could use this instead: `#ifndef _WIN32 #define closesocket(s) close(s) #endif` and then you can call `closesocket(m_nSocketHandle);` on all platforms unconditionally.

Comment: Thank you all for your information. Finally separating #ifdef/#endif from the application to library is for maintainability, cleaner code, and easy to debug? or any other additional advantage?

Answer (score 1):

> is this possible?

Yes, this is possible.

What you have written is exactly how cross platform libraries are written.

Some people prefer to not have ifdefs inside function definitions. An approach that avoids that is to use separate translations units for implementations on separate systems:

```
// win32.cpp
close_socket()
{
      closesocket(m_nSocketHandle);
} 

// apple.cpp
close_socket()
{
      close(m_nSocketHandle);
}


// linux.cpp
close_socket()
{
      shutdown(m_nSocketHandle,SHUT_RDWR);
}
```

and choose the source file to compile based on target system. This approach is not an option for templates or other inline functions. Choice between the approaches is subjective.

P.S. If you need different representation of state across systems, you can use PIMPL pattern to hide the system specific data.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Here I don't want to create multiple files for each platform. Instead i want the common code like as I did in the "call_socket" function (in the library) that has #ifdef. And I should call this function from the main application. If it is Windows platform, it will execute "closesocket" and if it is Linux, it will execute "close". Is it works like this?